# Haskell gets confused with horizontal lines

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, definition, guard-clause

I tried to practice haskell a bit but I didn't get the following code to work:

```
rems :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rems _ [] = []
rems k (x:xs)
  | k == x = rems k xs
  | otherwise [x] ++ rems k xs



main = print $
  rems 3 [5, 3, 2]
```

This function removes every k from a list x if you call it **rems k x**. I know that it should be working because we wrote it down in university.

I'm using this IDE: https://repl.it/languages/haskell

Comment: No you forgot a `=` after the `otherwise`, it is `otherwise = [x] ++ rems k xs`. You can improve it (slightly), by writing `otherwise = (x: rems k xs)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be useful to know that [`otherwise`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:otherwise) isn't a keyword or special symbol like `=`, it's actually simply a boolean value defined in the prelude as `True`. I.e., a guard with `otherwise` works syntactically the same as any other guard, just the condition is trivial. You might also write it

```
rems _ [] = []
rems k (x:xs)
  | k == x  = rems k xs
  | True    = [x] ++ rems k xs
```

The alignment I chose above (all `=` aligned and at least two<sup>†</sup> spaces away from the guard-condition) is completely a matter of taste, but I think it helps avoiding confusion like the one you've found yourself in.

BTW, `[x] ++ ...` can be shortened to `x : ...`. The preferred form of writing the function is

```
rems _ [] = []
rems k (x:xs)
  | k==x       = rems k xs
  | otherwise  = x : rems k xs
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Most people align the `=`s but use only one space. That's ok, but IMO `k == x = res` looks deceptive with all those equals-characters, and `k` and `x` further away from each other than from the result. `k==x  = res` seems tidier.</sub>

Comment: an additional extra space to the right of `=` as well is even clearer (and symmetry is beautiful). another terrible-looking type of code is with `let` on the RHS. `foo x | x == y = let z = bar y x in ...`. brr.

Comment: @WillNess well, it's _not_ symmetric – the RHS is really part of an `a = b` like in other definitions, but the LHS is something completely different. That's also a reason why I like to have extra space on the left.

Comment: it's the *space* around the `=` sign that ought to be symmetric IMO, guard or no guard. in any case it's aesthetically pleasing *to me* that way; YMMV.